# Assigning a value to a column in Dask.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I would like to use Dask to complete some data preprocessing with some very large files, 96 million and 5 million rows, about 10 columns, each. This is just happening on my laptop (which has 32GB of RAM.) Using Pandas causes the notebook to stall and then restart the Jupyter Server. So far, however, so does Dask.

The operation that's restarting the server is an attempt to cast IP addresses from float to int. When my dataframe loads, there are nan values for the IP addresses, which causes Pandas to recast the integer IPs as floats since there's not a nan/int type. So, I need to `dropna` and cast as `int`. Here's the code.

```
target_data = dd.read_parquet('file.parquet')
target_data = target_data.dropna()

# if this line is commented out, code works as anticipated.
target_data['ipv4_int'] = target_data.ipv4_address.astype(int)

target_data.groupby(groupby_cols).agg({"time_of_day": sum}).compute()
```

Is there a way to do this with Dask?

I verified that this code runs on a snippet of the full dataframe as a Pandas object.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to a [nullable integer type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), e.g. `Int64`, which supports `nan` values. Something like this:

```
target_data['ipv4_int'] = target_data.ipv4_address.astype('Int64')
```